# JSF Handler Class with Transactional Methods

Tags: hibernate, spring, properties, handler, transactional

i have a Handler-Class for a JSF page, but when i annotate the class or any Method with @Transactional, i get this Error, when accessing any Property in the JSF page:

Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @54,67 value="#{handler.startPage}": Property 'startPage' not found on type $Proxy115

any ideas why?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@Transactional`, spring will create a proxy for annotated class and it will be substituted for the original object. The default proxy creation algorithm it to use JDK proxies which rely on interfaces. In handler's interface there is no getter/setter for startPage property hence the exception.

You can either add getter/setter to the interface or enforce class based proxies. To enforce cglib proxies put below in your context file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi, i've dont this and it works, but the getter-functions of handlers are verry slow... something like 100ms... a jsf-list which fetches a value 40 times needs 4secs, any idea why cglib-classes are that slow?  EDIT: Sorry my fault, i annotated the whole class as transactional, so for every get there was a new transaction created

Comment: It sounds like you open database connection in getters called by JSF which is a very bad idea. They can't be marked as transactional. You should prepare your data when bean is created and getters should only return data available in memory. You can also try to fetch data lazily.

Comment: solved it already, i removed the transactional tag from the class an put it to the right methods, thanks